# Stack unable to find package in snapshot when an extra-dep is specified that is out of a dependency's version bounds

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I have a `package.yaml` containing

```
dependencies:
- aeson >= 0.8 && < 1.5
- base >= 4.7 && < 5
- time >= 1.5 && < 1.10
```

I want to use a newer version of `time` than is in the `lts-14.4` snapshot, so I create a `stack.yaml` with:

```
resolver: lts-14.4
packages:
- .
extra-deps:
- time-1.9.2
```

However when I run `stack build`, I get the output

```
WARNING: Ignoring aeson's bounds on time (>=1.4 && <1.9); using time-1.9.2.
Reason: trusting snapshot over cabal file dependency information.

Error: While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:

In the dependencies for base-compat-0.10.5:
    unix needed, but the stack configuration has no specified version  (latest matching version is 2.7.2.2)
needed due to tmphaskell-0.1.0.0 -> base-compat-0.10.5

Some different approaches to resolving this:

  * Recommended action: try adding the following to your extra-deps in /Users/will/src/tmphaskell/stack.yaml:

- unix-2.7.2.2@sha256:e69269a17b9fa26cb77f3f55e86c39d0a4940ccfa0c4bc20826919d2572076ad,3496

Plan construction failed.
```

What I don't understand about this `unix-2.7.2.2` *does* exist in the `lts-14.4` snapshot so why can't stack find the specified version?

This configuration worked for an older version of stack before I upgraded it to `2.1.3`. I'm not sure which version I was running previously.

Comment: I copy-pasted your configuration on a fresh new Stack project and `stack build` works fine on my machine. I think you either didn't provide enough information (maybe you have other dependencies? Or some specific piece of code?) or it's specific to your machine? Note: I'm on Windows.

Comment: @Sir4ur0n what version of `stack` are you using? As I said, this only seems to affect newer versions of stack.

Comment: The latest one (2.1.3)

Answer (score 0):

`aeson` (via `base-compat`) depends on `unix` and as `time` and `unix` are ghc boot packages, both need to be added as `extra-deps`.

The reason? [Boot libraries](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/wikis/commentary/libraries/version-history) don't have to match their hackage versions, so if you override a boot packages you must also explicitly override any others you use.

Source: https://www.snoyman.com/blog/2019/01/mismatched-global-packages

(edit fixed error; misread the precise error).

Comment: Interesting. Do you know why my configuration worked in a previous version of `stack`, but not with the latest version?

Comment: Semi related: `stack` currently prints `needed due to tmphaskell-0.1.0.0 -> base-compat-0.10.5`. Is there a way of printing the full dependency chain, e.g.: `tmphaskell-0.1.0.0 -> aeson -> base-compat-0.10.5`?

Comment: On the change, yes! It's new in stack 2.1. As to the full chain, I don't think there's an option. Would it be helpful?

Comment: Yes I think it would be useful. The example I posted here was a toy project. In reality my dependency graph was much more complex. I had to print out the whole dependency graph to figure out how I was depending on the packages listed in "the following exceptions were encountered".